# Nested divs and absolute position issue

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am puzzled by nested DIV's with Position set to absolute, perhaps someone could guide me :)

My goal is: 1 navbar with 2 div's for points and life, both containing text and 1 icon, i want to absolute position the div's so i can later manipulate them via jQuery.

my problem is, when i nest elements within my points and life div, they go all bananas for me, the overlap and top/right does not seem to have any effect, also the elements within the div's does not comply to my position:absolute, i've tried all sort of combinations with relative, absolute, display:block etc. but without any result.

i compiled a Fiddler to help visualize my problem:
[Fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/636kK/)

if i change the div's within points/life the icon seems to behave, but the h2 text is still giving me problems ?...

any idea/solution to my nested div chaos :D. .

```
    <div class="gameWrapper">
<div class="navBar">
        <div class="points">
            <h2>points</h2>
            <div class="imageClass"><div>
        </div>

        <div class="life">
            <h2>life</h2>
            <div class="imageClass"><div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

.gameWrapper{
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.gameWrapper .navBar{
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:69px;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.gameWrapper .navBar .points,
.gameWrapper .navBar .life{
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:15px;
}

.gameWrapper .navBar .points .imageClass,
.gameWrapper .navBar .life .imageClass{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    background: #fff url(http://drytech.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/pdf-icon.png) no-repeat 0;
}

.gameWrapper .navBar h2{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
}

.gameWrapper .navBar .points{
    right:140px;
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;   
}

.gameWrapper .navBar .life{
    right:50px;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS so people can read it without having to pull up the jsFiddle...

Comment: EDITED: i thought people would rather see it in action :).

Comment: The reason to post code is to make sure that questions in SO remain valid and readble even is jsFiddle or CodePen should disappear...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by closing your div tags for your `imageClass` elements.

Making the h2 tags inline would also help. You can either do this with `display: inline;` or changing them into a default inline element, like a `span`.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/636kK/3/)

Changing the `h2` tags into `span` tags, like I did for the fiddle, removes some of the default styling. Something to consider if you choose that route.

Comment: YUUP that did it, the </div> did it.... damn it's always the little things, i was totally blind to it, read my code over and over again, rewritten large sections etc... on the positive side, everything else seems to work in my project which means im getting the hang of this :D. thanks guy's for the second eye's :)